# Background image doesn't work on Safari v14 Catalina

Tags: reactjs, macos, background-image

I have my project almost done, but faced the issue that background image doesn't work on MacOS Catalina Safari version 14. Do you happen to know where the problem can be ? Thank you in advance!
ohh, I also should mention that project is written on React with TS.

```
.image {
  width: calc(100vw - 48rem);
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('../../public/img/auth-bg.jpg') left center no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  @include mobile() {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try This, public URL is base Url in the project you can it like this

```
.image {
  width: calc(100vw - 48rem);
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('/img/auth-bg.jpg') left center no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  @include mobile() {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, I can't link this way, cuz folder's structure doesn't allow to find img then

Comment: for using public folder in React app, you should use absolute path, "/" point to public folder